# Select objects where id = id from another object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list

I have `List<objectA>` with objects like:

```
productID int
price decimal
```

and `List<objectB>` with objects:

```
categoryID int
categoryName string
List<int> productList
```

Now, if I want to select all products from ListB with productID same as in ListA, I can do it like:

```
ListB.Where(x=>x.productList.Contains(LA.productID))
```

But how can I do something like:

```
ListA.Where(x=>x.productID in ListB.productList)
```

@@EIT:

```
public class product
{
    public int pID {get; set; }
    public decimal price {get; set; }
}


public class catAndProd
{
    public int categoryID { get; set; }
    public string categoryName { get; set; }
    public List<int> prodList { get; set; }
}
```

So my __prodCatList have elements like:

```
1,"Cat1", {1}
2,"Cat2", {2}
```

Now, ItemsSource to grid:

```
productsDG.ItemsSource = FastSellSearchClass.listaWar.Where(x => __prodCatList.Any(q => q.prodList.Contains(x.pID)));
```

Returns same Items to grid.
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Any` + `productList.Contains`:

```
var query = ListA
    .Where(a => ListB.Any(b => b.productList.Contains(a.productID)));
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I messed something, but with two products (product1, id = 1, catid = 1 and product2, id = 2, catid = 2) changing selection returns the same rows in grid.

Comment: @user13657: you speak in riddles ;-)

Comment: Guys, if you can, look at edit i've just made in first post :)

Comment: @user13657: sorry, but your edit doesn't make it clearer. What is `{1}` for example, the list with a single `int` which value is `1`? Also, does no list contain a productID of 1 or 2? Since we don't see sample data it's difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Yes, it is list. Sorry for missunderstanding. I forgot to add there "&& q.categoryID = selectedCategoryID". Work's great now :P

Answer (score 2):

you can use below menioned code

```
var abc=ListA.where(x=>ListB.Any(q=>q.ProductId==x.ProductId));
```

Comment: Fast, easy and helpful. Thanks ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter is right. Actually idea is ok, but I've just changed == to contains.